# Emacs Tramp - add proposed paths to TRAMP

Tags: emacs, ssh, elisp

I use the following method to connect to a remote host via emacs TRAMP :

```
C-x C-f /remotehost:filename  RET (or /method:user@remotehost:filename)
```

It works great, and `remotehost` can be one of my ssh aliases. However I still have to navigate the whole path for the `filename`, which can be quite long.

Is there a way to set up a default path (like a default `cd`) that would be pre-filled/proposed in the list (if existing for instance) when opening a new TRAMP/ssh connection to a particular host ?

Example :

```
C-x C-f /work-host:/
;; auto complete suggests some files, how do I suggest another file/path ?
```

*Note :* I am using Emacs prelude in case it matters

Answer (score 2):

You might navigate to your complete path, open a dired buffer, then save that as a bookmark (C-x r m). The next time you want to go there, just use the bookmark (C-x r b).

Comment: That's something worth investigating (don't know anything about bookmarks though).

Answer (score 1):

The Tramp manual explains in its FAQ section several ways to shorten paths. It's not exactly what you have asked for, but maybe it gives you some imagination what could be done.

Eval `(info "(tramp) Frequently Asked Questions")`